# Evaluating function names in R?

Tags: r, function

I was wondering why **#1** in my ***R code below*** produces correct output, but **#2** gives error? How can I fix **#2** error?

```
#1:
d = dnorm
d(0) ## Works OK! gives: [1] 0.3989423

#2:
d = c(dnorm, dcauchy)
d[1](0) ## Why does not work OK? gives: Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing `d` as a list:

```
d[[1]](0)

# [1] 0.3989423
```

Confirmation that `d` is actually a list:

```
typeof(d)

[1] "list"
```

Comment: Then `match.fun` is the key. Try `match.fun("dnorm")(0)`

Comment: And even `match.fun("*")(2,3)`